# Django: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I am trying to have two forms in one class based view. 
My view is:

```
class ListAndCreate(CreateView):
    model = xmpp_buddy_groups
    form_class = xmpp_buddy_groups_form
    second_form_class = sip_extension_form
    template_name = "xmpp/index.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('xmpp:index')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ListAndCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['object_list'] = self.model.objects.all()
        extension = SipExtension.objects.values_list('sip_extension', flat=True)
        for buddy_groups in group_names:
            for sip in buddy_groups.sipextension_set.all():
                sip_extension = sip.sip_extension
                print(sip_extension)
        context['extension'] = extension
        SipExtension.objects.exclude(sip_extension__in=extension)
        print(extension)
        context['form'] = self.form_class(request = self.request)
        context['form2'] = self.second_form_class(request=self.request)
        context['extensions'] = SipExtension.objects.exclude(sip_extension__in=extension)
        return context
```

I am getting error  **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'. Where am I going wrong?

My form classes:

```
from django import forms
from .models import xmpp_buddy_groups
from extensions.models import SipExtension
class xmpp_buddy_groups_form(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
      model = xmpp_buddy_groups
      fields = ['group_name']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     super(xmpp_buddy_groups_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     self.fields['group_name'].required = False

class sip_extension_form(forms.ModelForm):

   class Meta:
     model = SipExtension
     fields = ['real_name','sip_extension']
     widgets = {
            "sip_extension": forms.Select
           }
```

Comment: Have you defined your form classes to expect a `request` argument? Why are you passing it to them?

Comment: I have added my form classes. @DanielRoseman

Comment: Well as you can see neither of those are expecting `request` as an argument. Again, why are you passing it?